# How to change default theme of wso2carbon

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am new to wso2,I have a query that is it possible to change the default theme of wso2carbon.

Is there any way to customize that and i can use my own. I didn't get any output from their offcial doc..

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

[Playing Around With Carbon Product Themes](http://wso2.com/library/knowledge-base/2011/11/playing-around-carbon-product-themes/)